# RESTFul API endpoint design with filtering and authorization

Tags: rest, authorization, uri, endpoints

I am designing a REST API with consumers that have different permissions.  I understand that a representation of a resource should not change according to user.  Therefore I am trying to determine which is the best approach:

*GET - list collection of all documents - admin only.*:

/api/documents

*GET - list collection of all documents - any user with access to document 123*

/api/documents/123

For normal users therefore should the endpoints be

*list all documents for user 12*

/api/user/12/documents

*document 123 assuming user 12 has access*

/api/documents/123

OR... should the end points be as below and a query string filter used:

/api/documents?user=12

/api/documents/123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can get away with just two endpoints (and one header!). Make sure the API for `/documents` is returning the `Vary: Authorization` header. Then you can use

```
GET /api/documents              // return all docs the logged-in user can see
GET /api/documents?userId=bob   // return all of bob's docs that the logged-in user can see
GET /api/documents/123          // return doc 123 if the logged-in user can see it
```

It is not entirely unreasonable to nest the user a la `GET /api/users/bob/documents`. I find it to be harder for end users to learn APIs with a large number of endpoints, and I feel that the nested approach tends to create many endpoints. It's conceptually easier to go to `/documents` and see what you can filter on, rather than look at each endpoint and see what filters it has.

Comment: Thanks - though it is my understanding that a given end point should always return the same results, regardless of permissions.

So. GET /api/documents will return all documents no matter what.  If a user with a more limited role access this then they should get a 403 and use a different end point.

Comment: @JohnRoyal That's the purpose of the `Vary: Authorization` header. It lets any interested parties know that the results will vary based on the user's credentials. It is nice, but not always practical, for an endpoint to be user-agnostic. Certainly HTTP wasn't designed with that as an intended limitation, or there wouldn't be a Vary: Authorization header!

Comment: @JohnRoyal What if I try to PUT to /documents/123 when I don't have write access? I can read but not modify it. The author, though, can both GET and PUT to that document. Same URI, different results when different users make the same call. I don't see a fundamental difference between this case and GET returning different results based on auth.

Answer (score 6):

I would keep business logic and authorization logic entirely separate. If you want to retrieve document XYZ, you wouldn't pass the user id as an HTTP parameter.

You suggested `/api/documents?user=12` but in fact it should just be `/api/documents`. The user information should come from the authentication layer.

Similarly authorization should be entirely separate. The reasons for that are:

- separation of concern
- ability to update authorization logic independently of of business logic
- avoid impact on API design

The API should only reflect those business objects you care about e.g. documents in this case (possibly also users should you wish to display a user profile...).

To handle authentication, use the container's standard techniques (e.g. HTTP Basic authentication) or use advanced authentication techniques (OAuth..) via a dedicated framework.

To handle authorization, use a filter, an interceptor. In the Java world (where JAX-RS implements REST), have a look at the Jersey [interceptors and filters](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). You then want the interceptor (or policy enforcement point - PEP) to query an external authorization service (or policy decision point).

[image: Protecting a REST API - Architecture]

Have a further look at [ABAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/), the attribute-based access control model, and [XACML](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml), the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language which explain how to control access to your REST APIs without mixing business logic and authorization logic.