# Standard way to do access control for an online service

Tags: web-services, proxy, authorization

I was wondering what could be a standard way to do access control for some private online services which are hosted on the cloud?

Basically, the service on the cloud is a MapProxy, which itself does not support much authentication methods. Therefore, I was thinking to build a proxy in front of that Map Proxy to do some connection handling. We have decided to use cookies as a way of authentication, and now what is a standard way to do authorization?

Is there any well-documented library could help to build a connection handler for authorization ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean with *authorization*. If your goal is to define true access control logic e.g.:

- a user can call this method of my API if the user role is manager and the user location is the same as the location of the document requested in the API,

then you can use XACML, the [eXtensible Access Control Markup Language](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml). I have already replied to a similar question here: [RESTFul API endpoint design with filtering and authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303310/restful-api-endpoint-design-with-filtering-and-authorization/24322748#24322748) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514711/authorization-framework-in-a-java-web-application/24526891#24526891

To implement ABAC, you will need XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. It's an OASIS standard (the same body behind SAML and many other standards). XACML defines:

- a policy language to express the authorization requirements above
- a request/response scheme to query the authorization e.g. "Can Alice view document d?"
- an architecture which defines standard components such as the policy decision point (PDP) and the policy enforcement point (PEP). The latter protects your app and sends the authorization question to the PDP.

When to choose XACML (and ABAC) over other frameworks e.g. Spring Security (and RBAC)? If you have relationships between your users and your data (e.g. ownership, doctor-patient, team leader - team member...), then XACML is for you. If you have many different apps in different languages (Python, Java, .NET, Ruby...) then XACML is for you. XACML is technology-agnostic so it makes it easier to reuse across all your apps.

There are several frameworks that provide you with XACML. Some are vendor-based such as [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com/) (where I work). Others are open-source such as SunXACML or Heras AF.

HTH,
David.